# Why does it take couple of seconds for DNS resolver to find .local domain specified in etc/hosts

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, dns, domain

(Running Windows 7) This is one of the entries I have in my Windows' `etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost mysite.mike mysite.local
```

First I noticed that my browser takes always 2.01-2.04s (so 2 seconds) to resolve DNS on `mysite.local`. Sometimes the browser cached the dns entry but as soon as it expired, the situation happened again. However `mysite.mike` resolves immediately.

Now I checked if it's only the browser, so I used `tracert` tool to see how it reacts to dns resolving. The results were the same as in the browser although it took exactly 1s instead of 2s.

```
~  time tracert -4 mysite.local                                                                                                        
Tracing route to [127.0.0.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  [127.0.0.1]
Trace complete.
tracert -4 mysite.local  0.00s user 0.01s system 1% cpu 1.062 total
```

However

```
~  time tracert -4 mysite.mike
Tracing route to [127.0.0.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  [127.0.0.1]
Trace complete.
tracert -4 mysite.mike  0.00s user 0.01s system 32% cpu 0.047 total
```

I also noticed that tracert doesn't try to contact the DNS server (like it knows beforehand that both .mike and .local domains are local) on the internet as my FW doesn't trigger information which it does when I try to tracert any other domain such as `mysite.other`

What causes this 1-2 second delay?
Just a side note, it took Internet Explorer 10 seconds to resolve this very domain

Comment: Did you check traffic on ports udp/5353 and udp/5355?

Comment: I don't explicitly monitor the traffic but the interactive mode informs me upon connection attempt to allow/deny

Comment: Sounds like it's trying to resolve it via the mDNS service first, since it ends in ".local".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams this must have something to do with this. I uninstalled Apple's Bonjour (must have came with itunes) and the "problem" is gone.